# Program uploading to LPC 2148 by the time of component assembling

Tags: embedded, embedded-resource

I am developing an elevator GLCD display (128*64) with LPC2148 Micro controller, I have done program and PCB designing also. Now I want to upload the program to micro controller, how to do it? Before fixing micro controller or after fixing micro controller want to upload program?

Comment: You've done the PCB design by yourself and you don't know how to program the MCU ? I hope you didn't forget the debugger connector ;) Anyway if by chance you have a JTAG connector (or equivalent), you'll need to plug a debugger on it.

Comment: This is not the kind of "programming questions" suitable for this site. Try electronics.stackexchange, but first read their FAQ. Let that apart, your question is too broad/opinion based.

Comment: I am expecting different from your command, we required to program MCU without hardware connector, it mean before fixing the MCU  should  programmed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to program the device without using a bootloader or a JTAG. There is some standalone programmers available for the LPC2148 device. Example [here](https://www.elnec.com/en/device/Philips/LPC2141+%5BLQFP64%5D/). This will allow the MCU to be programmed before placing it on the board.

The maintainability of your design however raises red flags. You should at least have a JTAG header on the board even if it is not populated. JTAG is very flexible and cheap and add lots of development and testing options.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, than the LPC2100 series does have an ROM bootloader. You only have to pull a pin (I think P0.14) to ground while reset.

[Flashmagic](http://www.flashmagictool.com/) would than be a tool of choice to download the program.

Pro: No additional hardware needed.

Con: The bootloader pin and USART (normally USART0) need to be accessable.

Answer (score -1):

1.Use the Keil compiler to compile your code and 
generate hex file

2.Download and Install Flash Utility

3.In flash utility 
     Select Com port ,Board, Baud rate (may be default) and file

4.Now click on Upload to flash